# Is it possible to define a set $S=\{ x \ |\ 1<x \le 1\}$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I was wondering what would happen if I defined a set $S$ like this $S=\{ x\ | \ 1<x \le 1\}$.

My main question would be if defining $S$ like that would be valid in set theory or if it is inconsistent.

If it is a valid definition, what would this set look like? I think that if it was a valid statement, the set would be empty because there is no $x$ strictly bigger than $1$ and also smaller than or equal to $1$.

My main qualm is if it is a valid statement and if it is or is not, why?

Comment: It’s simply the empty set, just as if you’d defined $\{x:x\ne x\}$.

Comment: Yes, of course; it's just $\varnothing$, since no $x$ (presumably in $\mathbb{R}$ or something similar) satisfies the indicated condition.

Comment: It's valid, it's empty as well.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott so we do not have any kind of Russell Paradox situation on our hands?

Comment: @Guacho: That’s right: there’s nothing at all problematic about the definition. If $\varphi(x)$ is a formula such that $\forall x\big(\neg\varphi(x)\big)$ is true, then $\{x:\varphi(x)\}$ is simply $\varnothing$.